# How to update Row by above empty row in groups

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table

```
branch_no   crncy_id    Tax_1_Account   Tax_1_Balance       Tax_2_Account   Tax_2_Balance
1               3       01-01-211515    0.000000            NULL            NULL
1               3       01-01-230305    726910532.850000    NULL            NULL
1               3       NULL            NULL                01-01-240130    2019759.840000
1               3       01-01-240135    135117.090000       NULL            NULL
1               3       NULL            NULL                01-01-510170    2140859.810000
1               3       01-01-610501    0.000000            NULL            NULL
1               3       01-01-610520    37285.000000        01-01-610520    37285.000000
2               3       01-02-211515    0.000000            NULL            NULL
2               3       01-02-230305    14483229.720000     NULL            NULL
2               3       NULL            NULL                01-02-240130    85462.290000
2               3       01-02-240135    0.000000            NULL            NULL
2               3       NULL            NULL                01-02-510170    0.000000
2               3       01-02-610501    0.000000            NULL            NULL
2               3       01-02-610520    284409497.000000    01-02-610520    284409497.3             
3               3       01-03-211515    0.000000            01-03-211515    0.000000
3               3       01-03-230305    0.000000            01-03-230305    0.000000
3               3       NULL            NULL                01-03-240130    0.000000
3               3       01-03-240135    0.000000            01-03-240135    0.000000
3               3       NULL            NULL                01-03-510170    0.000000
3               3       01-03-610501    0.000000            01-03-610501    0.000000 
3               3       01-03-610520    710.000000          01-03-610520    710.000000
```

What I seek with is updating any NULLs that existing into `Tax_1_Account`, `Tax_1_Balance`, `Tax_2_Account` &  `Tax_2_Balance` with the value that in next row in case same group of `branch_no` And `Crncy_id` and keep NULL at the last group for `Tax_1_Account`, `Tax_1_Balance` Or `Tax_2_Account` &  `Tax_2_Balance` and delete record if there are NULLS into the 4 columns (`Tax_1_Account`, `Tax_1_Balance`, `Tax_2_Account` &  `Tax_2_Balance`)

Expected result:-

```
branch_no   crncy_id    Tax_1_Account   Tax_1_Balance       Tax_2_Account   Tax_2_Balance
1               3       01-01-211515    0.000000            01-01-240130    2019759.840000
1               3       01-01-230305    726910532.850000    01-01-510170    2140859.810000
1               3       01-01-240135    135117.090000       01-01-610520    37285.000000
1               3       01-01-610501    0.000000            NULL            NULL             
1               3       01-01-610520    37285.000000        NULL            NULL    
2               3       01-02-211515    0.000000            01-02-240130    85462.290000
2               3       01-02-230305    14483229.720000     01-02-510170    0.000000
2               3       01-02-240135    0.000000            01-02-610520    284409497.000000    
2               3       01-02-610501    0.000000            NULL            NULL
2               3       01-02-610520    284409497.000000    NULL            NULL
3               3       01-03-211515    0.000000            01-03-211515    0.000000
3               3       01-03-230305    0.000000            01-03-230305    0.000000
3               3       01-03-240135    0.000000            01-03-240130    0.000000
3               3       01-03-610501    0.000000            01-03-240135    0.000000
3               3       01-03-610520    710.000000          01-03-510170    0.000000
3               3       NULL            NULL                01-03-610501    0.000000 
3               3       NULL            NULL                01-03-610520    710.000000
```

Thanks.

Comment: Note that your question is poorly defined unless there exist one or more columns which provide the ordering you seem to think exists here (SQL tables are unordered _sets_ of records).

Comment: You need to show how "next" is defined (and it's not by just how you've pasted the data into your question)

Comment: Maybe, you mean ordering by ``tax_1_Account`` or ``tax_2_Account``. You should explain what is `` next row in group``

Comment: tbh, it looks more like you wanna "move up" the values by nulls, not copy them.

Comment: @siggemannen, You are right, I need to move them up by nulls.

Comment: To be honest the real problem here seems to be your design. You have violated 1NF with what is known as repeating groups. Once your design is not normalized even simple queries can become complicated. If you fixed the design so this was two tables achieving your desired output would be easy.

Comment: @SeanLange, I agree with you, but as you know, changing the structure with up and running environment is a lovely dream.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this perhaps:

```sql
select *
, identity(int, 1, 1) as id
into #t
from 
(
    VALUES  (1, 3, N'01-01-211515', N'0.000000', null, null)
    ,   (1, 3, N'01-01-230305', N'726910532.850000', null, null)
    ,   (1, 3, null, null, N'01-01-240130', N'2019759.840000')
    ,   (1, 3, N'01-01-240135', N'135117.090000', null, null)
    ,   (1, 3, null, null, N'01-01-510170', N'2140859.810000')
    ,   (1, 3, N'01-01-610501', N'0.000000', null, null)
    ,   (1, 3, N'01-01-610520', N'37285.000000', N'01-01-610520', N'37285.000000')
    ,   (2, 3, N'01-02-211515', N'0.000000', null, null)
    ,   (2, 3, N'01-02-230305', N'14483229.720000', null, null)
    ,   (2, 3, null, null, N'01-02-240130', N'85462.290000')
    ,   (2, 3, N'01-02-240135', N'0.000000', null, null)
    ,   (2, 3, null, null, N'01-02-510170', N'0.000000')
    ,   (2, 3, N'01-02-610501', N'0.000000', null, null)
    ,   (2, 3, N'01-02-610520', N'284409497.000000', N'01-02-610520', N'284409497.3')
    ,   (3, 3, N'01-03-211515', N'0.000000', N'01-03-211515', N'0.000000')
    ,   (3, 3, N'01-03-230305', N'0.000000', N'01-03-230305', N'0.000000')
    ,   (3, 3, null, null, N'01-03-240130', N'0.000000')
    ,   (3, 3, N'01-03-240135', N'0.000000', N'01-03-240135', N'0.000000')
    ,   (3, 3, null, null, N'01-03-510170', N'0.000000')
    ,   (3, 3, N'01-03-610501', N'0.000000', N'01-03-610501', N'0.000000')
    ,   (3, 3, N'01-03-610520', N'710.000000', N'01-03-610520', N'710.000000')
) t (branch_no,crncy_id,Tax_1_Account,Tax_1_Balance,Tax_2_Account,Tax_2_Balance)


select branch_no, crncy_id
, MAX(case when type = 1 then value end), max(case when type = 1 then bal end)
, MAX(case when type = 2 then value end), max(case when type = 2 then bal end)
from (

    select  row_number() over(partition by branch_no, crncy_id, type order by case when x.value is null then 1 else 0 end, id) as sort
    ,   *
    from    #t
    cross apply (
        select Tax_1_Account as value, Tax_1_Balance as bal, 1 as type
        union all
        select Tax_2_Account as value, Tax_2_Balance as bal, 2
        ) x
    ) x
group by sort,branch_no, crncy_id
having max(x.value) is not null
order by branch_no, crncy_id, sort
```

Note, i create manual identity field (id) which ensures "correct" sort, but you probably have some other field like date which should be used to sort this table.

The rest of logic is following.
I create two separate tables (type = 1 and type 2), that i sort by non-null values, and then i pivot them together to create the necessary final result.

`having max(x.value) is not null` removes the completely empty rows that occur after moving up

Comment: Appreciate, Thanks for your help.